# Add indicator arrow to Child Profile using flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht2V2.jpg)I am showing the two-child pic in appBar. But when I select

```html
child: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 15,
              centerTitle: true,
              title:Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0, right: 50.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<ViewStudentPersonAccountDetailsVOs>>(
                      future: EZStudentPerson.fetchStudentPersonDetails(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ViewStudentPersonAccountDetailsVOs>>snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.length == 0)
                          return Center(child: Text("Dashboard"));
                        return Center(
                            child: Row(
                              children: snapshot.data.length > 1 ? snapshot.data
                                  .map((user) => Card(
                                elevation: 1.0,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      studentSelected = user.studentId;
                                      SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
                                        prefs.setString("selectedStudentId",
                                            studentSelected.toString());
                                      });
                                    });
                                  },
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                          user.imageUrl,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        width:studentSelected == user.studentId ?
                                        SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 12 :SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 6,
                                        height:studentSelected == user.studentId ?
                                        SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 12 :SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 6,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                              )).toList() : snapshot.data
                                  .map((user) => Card(
                                elevation: 1.0,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                    child: ClipOval(
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        user.imageUrl,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        width:SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 12,
                                        height:SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 12,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                              )).toList(),
                            ));
                      }
                  ),
                )
              ),
            )),
```

one child need to show the indicator symbol in that child.

I mean selected pic need to show like that attachment:

[image]

I struck in the indicator symbol, I don't know how to add this indicator symbol.

Comment: Hi There. Update your question with details like what have done so far and where exactly are you stuck ? Questions without minimum reproducible code samples are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the arrow_drop_up icon ([documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/arrow_drop_up-constant.html)):

```
static const IconData arrow_drop_up = IconData(0xe5ae, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

And displace it as your needs!